# Node.js EJS Partials

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am sure that this is a problem due to my limited understanding of how EJS and partials work but I am facing what seems to be bizarre behavior in my Node.js app. I am using EJS as my templating engine and my basic directory structure is as follows:

```
- public
----- css
----- js
---------- main.js
- views
----- index.ejs
----- about.ejs
----- login.ejs
----- admin
---------- user.ejs
---------- categories.ejs
----- _layouts
---------- footer.ejs
---------- head.ejs
---------- header.ejs
---------- nav.ejs
---------- scripts.ejs
- package.json
- app.js
```

[Full Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyhgP.png)

My index.ejs is simply:

```
<% include _layouts/nav %>
<%- content %>
<% include _layouts/footer %>
```

Furthermore, the nav.ejs includes the head.ejs and the footer.ejs includes scripts.ejs.

Now the odd behavior is that on the index.ejs, everything works perfectly and is able to "find" main.js. However, whenever I go to about.ejs or login.ejs or anywhere other than index.ejs, it is not able to find main.js. If I "hard code" the main.js code into those files though, everything works as expected. I don't know if it is a problem with nesting includes with ejs files or if it is a relative/absolute links problem but it has been causing me grief for the last couple days. Any tips or advice is welcome! Thanks.

Comment: How are you including `main.js`? Do you see any errors in your browser console? Are the requests in the Network section using the correct URLs?

Comment: I am including main.js as part of the scripts.ejs file. <script src="js/main.js"></script>

Comment: What about my other questions?

Comment: have you added 
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`
in your app.js

Comment: you can make use of https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-partial

Comment: Oh sorry. I totally missed your other questions. I see a few errors in the console (all of which seem to have nothing to do with this) but I guess it is successfully finding the correct files. It is just not running the javascript in main.js how it should... Maybe it is something with absolute/relative paths in main.js or something like that. Here are images of what I'm seeing: https://imgur.com/a/6AGKQ.

Comment: @SantoshSuryawanshi, yes. I have included that. I have tried to set the public folder by:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
I have tried setting the folder using both methods (together and separately).

Comment: Consider using React instead of EJS for server-side rendering.

Comment: Why should I use React instead of EJS?

Comment: EJS is not maintained very well, it's an older library. Take a look at the EJS codebase and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to  your app.js and check
 
`let path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

your main.js file is not able to access public folder.

Comment: I think that fixed it actually. I was setting the public folder by using the following method:
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
But when I set it via your method, it fixed it. Thanks for the help!